What would a good loss function to penalize small diffrences?
Using MSE loss, the model is able to learn and make predictions, but I want to improve its performance.
From epoch 1, I am already getting a very small loss because the model is minimizing relatively similar tensors.
My goal is to further penalize the model so that the initial loss would be higher and emphasize even small differences.
What would be a better loss function ?
